# How do i associate excel file type (xlsx) with iPhone application

Tags: xcode4, ios5, uti

Hi
 i have managed to open .xls files form mail app by adding document type to the project build and set the Types field to "com.microsoft.excel.xls" (see screen shot).
I want to do the same with xlsx files but can't do it. I tried to add "com.microsoft.excel.xlsx" but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: i'm stell stucked in this issue !!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved that by defining custom UTI as follows. Try to add these definitions into your info.plist. It works as expected.

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>XLSX input table document</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>xlsx</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</string>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mydomain.myapplication.xlsx</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

....

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>

    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>XLSX input table document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.mydomain.myapplication.xlsx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 7):

The identifier for XLSX files is `org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Checkout: https://escapetech.eu/manuals/qdrop/uti.html

Comment: I don't know why nobody vote for your answer, but it's works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XSLX is already declared as `org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation`

Comment: That's PPTX, not XLSX.

Comment: And even if you do it like that, it doesn't work unless you add the custom UTI as in David's answer.